# What is the correct way to have a ChangeNotifier class depend on a Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a class called `MyChangeNotifier`. This class is required to have a behaviour run every time an `AppNotification` class is published to a stream. I have this working, but I am not sure if it is the correct way to do this with provider library.

I provide the `AppNotification` stream using `StreamProvider` as follows...

```
MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ...,
          StreamProvider<AppNotification?>.value(value: _notificationService.notificationsStream, initialData: null),
        ],
        child: ...
      ),
```

Then down the widget tree I have a StatlessWidget whose job it is to specifically consume the AppNotification events from the stream, and pass them to the MyChangeNotifier class..

```
class AppNotificationConsumer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const AppNotificationConsumer(this.child , {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppNotification?>(
      builder: (context , notification , widget) {
        if (notification != null) {
            var model = Provider.of<MyChangeNotifer>(context , listen: false);
            WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
              model.handleNotification(notification);
            });
          }
        }
        return child;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here I have this logic wired up in the build method of a `StatelessWidget`. I have to use addPostFrameCallback because the `handleNotification` call, calls the overlay_support libray `showNotification()` which walks the widget tree (cannot be called in build).

Is there a way using a provider that I can bind the `MyChangeNotifier` and the `AppNotification` stream without using a `StatelessWidget`....or is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do it. Just use the [`ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html)

It would be like this:

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ...,
    StreamProvider<AppNotification?>.value(value: _notificationService.notificationsStream, initialData: null),
    // Here   ---v
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AppNotification?, MyChangeNotifer>(
      create: (_) => MyChangeNotifer(),
      update: (_, notification, myChangeNotifier) =>
          myChangeNotifier!..handleNotification(notification),
    ),
  ],
  child: ...
),
```

Every time there is a new `AppNotification` the update is called giving the chance to update other things. There is also `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider2`, `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider3` (and so on) with 2 or 3 other dependencies respectively instead of just 1.